# neo4j - Count the number of duplicates in result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, counting

Community,

I am new to neo4j and I'm trying to get a list of nodes (that has not a specific relation) and count node name duplicates.

Query:

```
MATCH (e:ExampleNode)
WHERE NOT exists((e)-[:EXAMPLE_REL]->())
RETURN e.name as name, count(e.name) as count
```

Result:

| name | count |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 3 |
| name23 | 1 |
| name8 | 4 |

So far so good...

Beside the name of the node I also need some more values. This value makes each result unique and returns every node separately even (if the name is the same).

Query:

```
MATCH (e:ExampleNode)
WHERE NOT exists((e)-[:EXAMPLE_REL]->())
RETURN e.name as name, count(e.name) as count, e.property as someValue
```

Result:

| name | count | someValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 | abc |
| name1 | 1 | cba |
| name1 | 1 | xyz |
| name23 | 1 | abc |
| name8 | 1 | 123 |
| name8 | 1 | 321 |
| name8 | 1 | 987 |
| name8 | 1 | 789 |
| ... | ... | ... |

But...this is the result I would like to have:

| name | count | someValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 3 | abc |
| name1 | 3 | cba |
| name1 | 3 | xyz |
| name23 | 1 | abc |
| name8 | 4 | 123 |
| name8 | 4 | 321 |
| name8 | 4 | 987 |
| name8 | 4 | 789 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like to return every node that hasn't the specific relation and count all duplicates by the name.

So, is it possible to get the result I would like to have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yess it is possible. When calculating the count, collect the property values in a list using `collect` function and then use `UNWIND` on the previous list, to get distinct rows for each property. Like this:

```
MATCH (e:ExampleNode) 
WHERE NOT exists((e)-[:EXAMPLE_REL]->()) 
WITH e.name as name, count(e.name) as count, collect(e.property) as properties 
UNWIND properties as property 
RETURN name, count, property
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this very quick and useful answer. This absolutely solved my problem. Thanks. +1